# Is six.text_type the same as text.decode('utf8')?

Tags: python, text, unicode, six

Given a function like:

```
import six

def convert_to_unicode(text):
  """Converts `text` to Unicode (if it's not already), assuming utf-8 input."""
  if six.PY3:
    if isinstance(text, str):
      return text
    elif isinstance(text, bytes):
      return text.decode("utf-8", "ignore")
    else:
      raise ValueError("Unsupported string type: %s" % (type(text)))
  elif six.PY2:
    if isinstance(text, str):
      return text.decode("utf-8", "ignore")
    elif isinstance(text, unicode):
      return text
    else:
      raise ValueError("Unsupported string type: %s" % (type(text)))
  else:
    raise ValueError("Not running on Python2 or Python 3?")
```

Since `six` handles the python2 and python3 compatibility, **would the above `convert_to_unicode(text)` function be equivalent to just `six.text_type(text)`?** I.e.

```
def convert_to_unicode(text):
    return six.text_type(text)
```

Are there cases that the original `convert_to_unicode` capture but `six.text_type` can't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `six.text_type` ist just a reference to the `str` or `unicode` type, an equivalent function would be this:

```
def convert_to_unicode(text):
    return six.text_type(text, encoding='utf8', errors='ignore')
```

But it doesn't behave the same in the corner cases, eg. it will just happily convert an integer, so you'd have to put some checks there first.

Also, I don't see why you would want to have `errors='ignore'`.
You say you assume UTF-8.
But if this assumption is violated, you are silently deleting data.
I would strongly suggest using `errors='strict'`.

#### EDIT:

I just realised this doesn't work if `text` is already what you want.
Also, it happily raises a TypeError for any non-string input.
So how about this:

```
def convert_to_unicode(text):
    if isinstance(text, six.text_type):
        return text
    return six.text_type(text, encoding='utf8', errors='ignore')
```

The only corner case uncovered here is that of the Python version being neither 2 nor 3.
And I still think you should use `errors='strict'`.

Comment: Note: `six` version 1.12 has `six.ensure_text()` which I suppose does just what you need.

Comment: @alvas, is there something you were missing from my answer? Like an explanation why this covers all cases from the function you posted?